# Basic use of openssl parameters and key generation

Tags: ssl, encryption, openssl, cryptography, public-key-encryption

Using openssl, I am trying to generate shared parameters with Diffie-Hellman with  2048 modulus.

I believe that I can do this like this: `openssl dhparam -C 2048`

But, I am trying to complete the whole algorithm and am following a tutorial here:
https://sandilands.info/sgordon/diffie-hellman-secret-key-exchange-with-openssl

This tutorial I believe uses the line: `openssl genpkey -genparam -algorithm DH -out dhp.pem` to generate the same thing but without using the 2048 modulus (i could be wrong here).

How do integrate my use of `dhparam` instead of `genpkey` into this tutorial so that I can choose the modulus of 2048, **or** how do I choose the modulus of `genpkey` **or** am I fundamentally misunderstanding something here?

Comment: Does adding `-pkeyopt:dh_paramgen_prime_len:2048` to the `genpkey` variant not do what you expect?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`genpkey` is the general purpose key generation utility of `openssl`.

`dhparam` is dedicated to diffie-hellman.

Both can be used for the same purpose. In you context you would have to use either

```
openssl genpkey -genparam -algorithm DH -pkeyopt dh_paramgen_prime_len:2048
```

or

```
openssl dhparam 2048
```